# How to check if there's no previous output

Tags: python, output, logic

I'm writing a Python program and I'm trying to print out a statement if there isn't any other output.

So, for example:

z is 0 and amount is 70

```
for z in range(amount):
    temp2=input2[1][:-3] #for this case lets say the value is 8
    temp=k[z] #array of numbers
    if temp.startswith(temp2,0,1)==True:#this is the conditioning statment
        #this is the output for the condition no bother
        stdout.write(f'{crn[z]} {sub[z]} {cn[z]} {sec[z]}'+" ")
        stdout.write(f'{days[z]} {bt[z]} {et[z]} {inst[z]}\n')
```

What I'm trying to do now is print out a statement, such as `NO MATCHES FOUND`, if none of the numbers in the array of numbers start with `temp2`. How do I go about that?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Please edit it and make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize a Boolean flag as `False` and set it to `True` when the condition is met, and print the not found message if the flag remains `False` after the `for` loop:

```
found = False
for z in range(amount):
    temp2=input2[1][:-3] #for this case lets say the value is 8
    temp=k[z] #array of numbers
    if temp.startswith(temp2,0,1)==True:#this is the conditioning statment
        #this is the output for the condition no bother
        stdout.write(f'{crn[z]} {sub[z]} {cn[z]} {sec[z]}'+" ")
        stdout.write(f'{days[z]} {bt[z]} {et[z]} {inst[z]}\n')
        found = True
if not found:
    print('NO MATCHES FOUND')
```